# What is the difference between jasmine error of Timeouts in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine, timeout, protractor

What is the difference between those error of Timeouts in protractor while using **jasmine framework** :

- Timed out waiting for asynchronous script result after xx ms
- jasmine: Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) should answer your question